# От чего нужно защищать формы?

Tags: веб-программирование, безопасность, csrf

Я имею довольно печальные знания по поводу безопасности веб-приложений, и сейчас пытаюсь разобрать тему защиты форм.

Пока что знаю, что нужно:
- защищать от повторной отправки
- от CSRF (можно вроде объединить с предыдущим)
- от спама
- от неправильных/вредных данных типа неправильных имейл адресов или sql-инъекций

Что еще можно добавить? О чем человек должен думать, когда решает обеспечить безопасность форм?

Comment: специально для вас умные люди написали обучающий курс https://habrahabr.ru/company/pentestit/blog/327270/

Comment: Спасибо за ценную информацию, будем читать :)